# Download many plots from shinyapp

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Problem:

I have a large amount of data I am trying visualize for my users. This may be several hundred plots. In the app currently I am making ggplot2 small multiples using facet_wrap and that's working pretty well up to around 100 plots. However, I want the user to be able to export all of the plots as a record of what they have done and also to be able to visualize all of the plots, not just the first 100. I'm not too worried how it's formatted (ie as a ggforce::facet_wrap_paginate() or as completely separate plots as below).

I have tried several approaches I found on stack-overflow but nothing seems to be working

The following code works if I try and export the plots in R but I can't get the download in shiny to work.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(

  downloadButton("plot_download", "Download all plots"),
  plotOutput("facet_plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  
  data <- reactive({
    
    data.frame(group = rep(LETTERS, each = 100),
               x = runif(n = 20, min = 10, max = 15),
               y = runif(n = 20, min = 100, max = 150))
    
  })
  
  

    output$facet_plot <- renderPlot({
      data() |>
        ggplot(aes(x,y)) +
        geom_point() +
        facet_wrap(vars(group))
        
    })
    
    
    output$plot_download <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste0(Sys.Date(), "_plot.pdf")
      },
      content = function(file) {

        pdf(file)
        data() |>
          split(by="group") |>
          lapply(function(data) {
            gg <- data |>
              ggplot(aes(x,y)) +
              geom_point() 
          })
        dev.off()

      }
    )
    
    
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling the `pdf` function, you can use `ggsave` function. It will save the output in the desired format with parameters like `width`, `height`, `dpi`, and `units`.
You can find the documentation [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsave.html).

The code will look like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  downloadButton("plot_download", "Download all plots"),
  plotOutput("facet_plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- reactive({
    data.frame(group = rep(LETTERS, each = 100),
               x = runif(n = 20, min = 10, max = 15),
               y = runif(n = 20, min = 100, max = 150))
  })
  
  output$facet_plot <- renderPlot({
    data() %>%
      ggplot(aes(x,y)) +
      geom_point() +
      facet_wrap(vars(group))
  })
  
  output$plot_download <- downloadHandler(
    filename =  function() {
      paste0(Sys.Date(), "_plot.pdf", sep = '')
    },
    content = function(file) {
      ggsave(file, data() %>% ggplot(aes(x, y)) + geom_point()+ facet_wrap(~group), dpi = 300)
    } 
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

P.S: I've changed a few things here and there in your code. The code to save the plot should work with your previous code.

**EDIT**
In order to scale the solution according to your needs, I made a few changes to the code.
There's a package called `ggforce`. You can find about it [here](https://ggforce.data-imaginist.com/). It will help you save the plots from `facet_wrap` as individual graphs on single pages or in rows and column-wise fashion.

Here's how the code will look like:

```
filename =  function() {
      paste0(Sys.Date(), "_plot.pdf", sep = '')
    },
    content = function(file) {
      pdf(file)
      #ggsave(file, data() %>% ggplot(aes(x, y)) + geom_point()+ facet_wrap(~group), dpi = 300)
      for(i in 1:length(unique(data()$group))) {
        print(data() %>% ggplot(aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + 
          facet_wrap_paginate(~group, ncol = 1, nrow = 1, page = i))
      }
      dev.off()
    }
```

Notice that, I'm using for group based on your sample data. You can change it according to your needs. `facet_wrap_paginate` is the function you require here. You can specify the number of columns and rows of plots you want to save on each page with it.

Comment: Thanks that does work, however I'm unsure if that will work for my app. I hadn't considered using just ggsave because I thought I would want to split the plots across several pages in a PDF. That's why I had used the PDF function. 

The number of plots will vary depending on the users own unique data that they upload. So the number of facets in this case could vary from just a few to several hundred. Will this scale well if I make the export size dynamic based on the number of facets and there's one ginormous PDF page?

Comment: I have edited my answer based on your requirements. Using `facet_wrap_paginate` you can get control over how you show the plots in a pdf.

Comment: If that does answer your question please consider upvoting and accepting the answer using the grey tick on the left of this answer.